# Update with Join hibernate (HQL)

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, join, hql

I'm on trouble with an hql problem.

I would like to write a query, that updates an attribut, and that's based on a value on another table.

This is my example, I have those two tables : Client and Widhdrawal.

Client : idClient, name ...

Widhdrawal : idWidh, cost, and the idClient (foreign key)

Now if i would update the client, under the condition of (idClient = 5 for example), i can't.

I tried this, but in vain :

```
        String hql = "UPDATE Widhdrawal W set W.cost = :salary "  + 
    "where W.Client.id_client = :employee_id)";

    Query query = session.createQuery(hql);
    query.setParameter("salary", 1000);
    query.setParameter("employee_id", 5);
    int result = query.executeUpdate();
```

I hope that someone can have some advices, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 String hql = "UPDATE Widhdrawal W set W.cost = :salary "  + 
          "where W.idClient = :employee_id)";
```

Comment: dosen't work .


"could not resolve property: idClient of: com.isamm.beans.Widhdrawal"

I think that's because of attribut in Widhdrawal :


'
public class Widhdrawal{

 private int idWidh;
 private String libelle;
 private String date;
 private double somme;
 private Client client;
'

Answer (score 0):

Thank you, i found the solution.
I hope that this can help other people ...
This problem is du to lowerCase.

```
                String hql = "UPDATE Widhdrawal W set W.cost= :newCost "  + 
                      "where W.client.id_client = :id_cl";

            Query query = session.createQuery(hql);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```java
String hql = "UPDATE Widhdrawal W set W.cost = :salary "  + 
    "where W.id_client =(select id_client from client where id_client = :employee_id)";
```

Widhdrawal  and client is POJO class name.