# Update query wih join in HQL

Tags: java, hibernate

I have two tables `RootOprs` and `ChildOprs`, where `RootOprs` can have multiple `ChildOprs`

I want to update 2 column in `RootOprs` table and one column in `ChildOprs` with bulk data

```
Update ChildOpr c 
Left join Fetch c.rootOpr 
set c.status=:status,
r.status=:staus
r.oprtimestamp=:timestamp
where c.id IN :childOperIDList;
```

This query is not working. Does anyone have better approach than this? Please help.

Comment: Possible duplicate 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15514021/update-with-join-hibernate-hql

Comment: Nopes, its a different question where I want to update two tables in Hibernate (HQL ) using @NamedQuery annotation